# Find the next sibling of the td that contains the specific text and store it in a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this table which im trying to scrape using Python/Beautiful Soup.

Also I have this code:

```
desc_seven = page_soup.find.nextSibling('strong', text='Description 7')
print(desc_seven.text.strip())
```

What I'm trying to do is **FIND** the text "Description 7" then go to the text beside it and store it in a variable so I can easily `print` it.

The output should be **"HHH"** if i do the `print(desc_seven.text.strip())`.

My code doesn't work saying there's no attribute 'nextSibling'. Also, is it possible to do it without using any (for) loops because I will capture several `td` and store it in a variable individually.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 1</strong></td>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td><strong>Description 11</strong></td>
    <td>LLL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 2</strong></td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    <td><strong>Description 12</strong></td>
    <td>MMM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 3</strong></td>
    <td>CCC</td>
    <td><strong>Description 13</strong></td>
    <td>NNN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 4</strong></td>
    <td>EEE</td>
    <td><strong>Description 14</strong></td>
    <td>OOO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 5</strong></td>
    <td>FFF</td>
    <td><strong>Description 15</strong></td>
    <td>PPP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 6</strong></td>
    <td>GGG</td>
    <td><strong>Description 16</strong></td>
    <td>QQQ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 7</strong></td>
    <td>HHH</td>
    <td><strong>Description 17</strong></td>
    <td>RRR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 8</strong></td>
    <td>III</td>
    <td><strong>Description 18</strong></td>
    <td>SSS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 9</strong></td>
    <td>JJJ</td>
    <td><strong>Description 19</strong></td>
    <td>TTT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Description 10</strong></td>
    <td>KKK</td>
    <td><strong>Description 20</strong></td>
    <td>UUU</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Appreciate your help on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use `find_next()` after you have found you "strong" element:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
strong = soup.find('strong', text='Description 7')
desc_seven = strong.find_next('td')
print(desc_seven.text.strip())
```

Outputs:

> HHH

You can do it in one line:

```
desc_seven =  soup.find('strong', text='Description 7').findNext('td').get_text(strip=True)
print(desc_seven)
```

Outputs:

> HHH